# Smoothing corner after beveling issue

Tags: bevel, smooth

Can the result of beveling a single corner be better? To see a better shade smooth's work

[image: Bevel]

Comment: Hello, maybe take a look at my answer here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/199792/rounded-corners-but-not-as-you-know-them-messing-up-the-mesh-for-sub-divisio/199828#199828

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*AutoSmooth* set to *30°* causes shading artifacts on beveled corner edges.
 If you want to get better shading you need to:

1. Select edges around the beveled corner and press <kbd>RMB</kbd> *> Mark Sharp*
2. <kbd>TAB</kbd> to switch back to *Object Mode*
3. <kbd>RMB</kbd> *> Shade Smooth*
4. *Object Data Properties > Normals > Auto Smooth* check the box and set value to *180°*
   [image: Sharp This Edges]
   [image: Corner Vertex Bevel SetUp]

Another way to solve the shading problem and make corneres of the cube smoother is to bevel the edges insted of vertices(topology change will lead to better shading)

1. Select the desired edges
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> to bevel
3. At the bottom left in settings dialog set *Inner > Arc* and change the size of corner bevel by tweeking *Spread* value.
4. Check the box next to *Harden Normals*

[image: Corner Edge Bevel SetUp]